# Area of 4 sides of a rectangle?? (Application of derivative)

Tags: derivatives, area

> A rectangular storage container with an open top is to have a volume of $10$ m$^3$. The length of its base is twice the width. Material for the base costs \$10 per square meter. Material for the side costs \$6 per square meter. Find the cost of materials for the cheapest such container.

I need to find the total cost of the container in terms of $w$ before I can find the minimum cost by the 1st or 2nd derivative test.

Assume $w$ is width, so length is $2w$, Volume = $2w^2h =10$ so, $h=5/w^2$.

Finding cost:

Total cost of material for base = $10 (2w^2) = 20w^2 $

Total cost of material for the 4 sides = $6 ( 2wh + 2h(2w))$

I do not understand why the area of the 4 sides is $2wh + 2h(2w)$.Isnt it just finding the area of rectangle multiply by 4 which is $ 4 (2w)(w)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The 4 rectangles have different lengths, two length 2w and two width w (both height h). So the two on opposite sides of the box have the same length/width respectively. Try drawing a picture

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions of the base are $w$ and $2w$. So, area of the base is $2w^2$.

Now we have $4$ rectangular sides of the container.

Two of these rectangles are rising above the $w$ dimension of the base. Thus, area of one such rectangle is $wh$. Area of both these rectangles is $2wh$.

Other two rectangular sides of the container are rising above $2w$ dimension of the base. Thus, area of one such rectangle is $h(2w)$. Area of both these rectangles is $2h(2w)$.

Therefore, total area of $4$ sides is $2wh+2h(2w)$.